# Laravel build a route from a model

Tags: php, library, laravel

I've created a library, [TomHart/laravel-route-from-model](https://github.com/TomHart/laravel-route-from-model), and looking to get a review on it. As well as the usual code review, I'm also looking for feedback from a users point of view, if you were to use the library, is there anything extra you wish it did, anything different etc.

The key class is:

```php
<?php
namespace TomHart\Routing;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException;
class RouteBuilder
{
    /**
     * Get the router instance.
     *
     * @return Router
     */
    private function getRouter(): Router
    {
        return app('router');
    }
    /**
     * Get the UrlGenerator.
     *
     * @return UrlGenerator
     */
    private function getUrlGenerator(): UrlGenerator
    {
        return app('url');
    }
    /**
     * This allows a route to be dynamically built just from a Model instance.
     * Imagine a route called "test":
     *      '/test/{name}/{id}'
     * Calling:
     *      routeFromModel('test', Site::find(8));
     * will successfully build the route, as "name" and "id" are both attributes on the Site model.
     *
     * Further more, once using routeFromModel, the route can be changed. Without changing the call:
     *      routeFromModel('test', Site::find(8));
     * You can change the route to be:
     *      '/test/{name}/{id}/{parent->relationship->value}/{slug}/{otherParent->value}'
     * And the route will successfully change, as all the extra parts can be extracted from the Model.
     * Relationships can be called and/or chained with "->" (Imagine Model is a Order):
     *      {customer->address->postcode}
     * Would get the postcode of the customer who owns the order.
     *
     * @param string  $routeName The route you want to build
     * @param Model   $model     The model to pull the data from
     * @param mixed[] $data      Data to build into the route when it doesn't exist on the model
     *
     * @return string The built URL.
     */
    public function routeFromModel(string $routeName, Model $model, array $data = [])
    {
        $router = $this->getRouter();
        $urlGen = $this->getUrlGenerator();
        $route = $router->getRoutes()->getByName($routeName);
        if (!$route) {
            throw new RouteNotFoundException("Route $routeName not found");
        }
        $params = $route->parameterNames();
        foreach ($params as $name) {
            if (isset($data[$name])) {
                continue;
            }
            $root = $model;
            // Split the name on -> so we can set URL parts from relationships.
            $exploded = collect(explode('->', $name));
            // Remove the last one, this is the attribute we actually want to get.
            $last = $exploded->pop();
            // Change the $root to be whatever relationship in necessary.
            foreach ($exploded as $part) {
                $root = $root->$part;
            }
            // Get the value.
            $data[$name] = $root->$last;
        }
        return rtrim($urlGen->route($routeName, $data), '?');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Laravel coupling

What a shame that you decided to tie this to laravel. You can decouple the entire library from laravel framework and only provide a bundle for laravel.

`routeFromModel` accepts `Model`, but it can actually work for any object.

```
$route = $router->getRoutes()->getByName($routeName);
if (!$route) {
  throw new RouteNotFoundException("Route $routeName not found");
}
$params = $route->parameterNames();
```

This means you really don't need the router, you just need something that gives you an "array of prameter names" based on a "name".

```
return rtrim($urlGen->route($routeName, $data), '?');
```

Returning just the data here would make it more flexible.

## IoC

You are pulling the RouteBuilder from DI container, why not have the container inject those deps. The way it is now, it could just be a static class with only static methods...

Comment: Ahh interesting! I never thought of it as anything but Laravel, but yeah that makes sense. I'll try and decouple it as an exercise, see what can be done, thanks :)!

Comment: I did as you recommended, pulled the core logic into it's own [repo](https://github.com/TomHart/array-from-object), and made use of that in the laravel specific library.